# http:<server>/_api/web/webs 401 unauthorized

Tags: jquery, rest, 401, requestexecutor

i'm using a jquery script embedded in a SharePoint page. i am able to load the results of a /_api/web/webs call to REST as myself (site collection admin). However, anyone that visits the page that is not a site collection admin (even users with Full Control access) are met with a prompt to enter their login credentials. After inputing their credentials three times, they are met with a 401 Unauthorized error.

It seems like just about any other api call works for just about all the users but specifically _api/web/webs is unauthorized.

Any information on why this particular call would require elevated privileges or if i am doing something wrong would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var root;
$(function () {
     var pathname = window.location.pathname; // Returns path only
     var url      = window.location.href;
     root = url.substring(0,(url.length - pathname.length));
     $.getScript(root + "/_layouts/15/SP.RequestExecutor.js", getWebInfo) ; 
});

function getWebInfo(){
var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(root);    
executor.executeAsync({
    url: root + "/_api/web/webs",
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"},
    success: successfulCall,
    error: failureCall
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do these users have permissions to the subsites? Also, why use `RequestExecutor`? That's the cross-domain library for use in an appweb.  You can simply use `$.ajax({url: "/_api/web/webs"});`, since you're on the same domain.

Comment: For testing purposes they have been given full control.

requestExecutor was only used to try to troubleshoot permissions issue. It is not necessary to keep.

Comment: Do all subsites inherit permissions? Doesn't matter if they have full control to a site, if the sub site has separate permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there were some subsites with unique permissions. I added the security trimming filter at the end of the call and it fixed the issue.

```
/_api/web/webs/?$filter=effectivebasepermissions/high%20gt%2032
```

Thanks for your help